# How to represent a player on a grid in four in a line

Tags: java

The code below is the board class part of the four in a line code. I succeeded in making a grid, but it is difficult to express a player on the grid.
I succeeded in printing the grid, but I failed to print the player on the desired part I wanted.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Board board = new Board(13, 6);
        SelectLine selLine = new SelectLine();
        selLine.input();
        board.put(selLine);
        }
}

    public class Board {
     char[][] string;  
     char[][] om;
     int width;
     int height;
     int count;
     Practice1 practice = new Practice1();
    
    public Board(int width, int height){

        count = 0;
        string = new char[height][width];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
                if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                    
                    string[i][j] = '┌';
                }
                else if(j % 2 == 1) {
                    string[i][j] = '─';
                }
                else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1){
                    string[i][j] = '┐';
                }
                else if (i == height-1 && j == 0){
                
                    string[i][j] = '└';
                }
                else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1){
                    string[i][j] = '┘';
                }
                else if (i == 0){
                    string[i][j] = '┬';
                }
                else if (j == 0){
            
                    string[i][j] = '├';
                }
                else if (i == height - 1){
                    string[i][j] = '┴';
                }
                else if (j == width - 1){
                    string[i][j] = '┤';
                }
                else  
                    string[i][j] = '┼';
            }
        }
    }

    public void print(){
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
                System.out.print(string[i][j]);
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public void put(SelectLine setLine) {

        int x=setLine.getX();
        int y=setLine.getX();
        if(string[(x-1) * 2][y-1] =='○' || string[(x-1) * 2][y-1] == '●')

            System.out.println("Select Again");
        else if(count%2 == 0){
            this.string[x-1][y-1] = '●';
            count++;
        }
        else{
            this.string[x-1][y-1] = '○';
            count++;
        }
        this.print();
        }


}

    public class SelectLine {
    int line;
    int type;
    public void input(){
        System.out.print("Select Line : ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        line = scan.nextInt();
    
    }
    public int getX(){
        return line;

    }
}
```

The image below is printed using the board class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX3wU.png)

I want to know how to express the player on the grid like the second image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOrT7.png)

Comment: What is the exact problem you have? You can express the player by coordinates `x` and `y`. Where do you stuck?

Comment: I finished printing the grid.
My exact problem is to make a conditional statement that outputs the player on the grid.

Comment: But what is the problem? A simple `if()` statement can check if at the indices `i,j` is a player. Depending on your code it can be as simple as `... else if (i == player_x && j == player_y) { string[i][j] = '•'; } ...`.

Comment: @Kevin `int y=setLine.getX();`, that looks like you meant to write `getY();`. You might want to learn how to use a debugger in your IDE.