# How to express a player on a board in a connect four game

Tags: java

The numbers entered in selectline are well implemented up to the second line of the board.
But it doesn't work from the third line.
What should I do?
The following is part of my code

As shown in the picture below, it should be printed on the third line, the fourth line...
I am printed only until the second line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAr0y.png)

```java
public class Practice1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Board board = new Board(13, 6);
        SelectLine selLine = new SelectLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            selLine.input();
            board.put(selLine);
        }
    }

}

public class SelectLine {
    int line;
    public void input() {
        System.out.print("Select Line : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        line = sc.nextInt();

    }
    public int getY() {
        return line;

    }
}

public class Board {
    char[][] string;
    char[][] om;
    int width;
    int height;
    int count;


    public Board(int width, int height) {

        count = 0;
        string = new char[height][width];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {

                    string[i][j] = '┌';
                } else if (j % 2 == 1) {
                    string[i][j] = '─';
                } else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1) {
                    string[i][j] = '┐';
                } else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0) {

                    string[i][j] = '└';
                } else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1) {
                    string[i][j] = '┘';
                } else if (i == 0) {
                    string[i][j] = '┬';
                } else if (j == 0) {

                    string[i][j] = '├';
                } else if (i == height - 1) {
                    string[i][j] = '┴';
                } else if (j == width - 1) {
                    string[i][j] = '┤';
                } else
                    string[i][j] = '┼';
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                System.out.print(string[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void put(SelectLine setLine) {

        int y = setLine.getY();
        int x = 6;
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            if (string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] == '●' || string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] == '○') {
                x -= 1;
                string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] = '●';
                count++;
            } else {
                string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] = '●';
                count++;
            }
        } else {
            if (string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] == '●' || string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] == '○') {
                x -= 1;
                string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] = '○';
                count++;
            } else {
                string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] = '○';
                count++;
            }
        }
        this.print();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You're only ever setting the dots in the `string[][]` at `string[5][]` or `string[4]`, which after every turn you set X to 6 then only subtract 1 or 0 from it before placing.  You need to (loop) through all the `x` values at the chosen `y` instead of just hardcoding `x-1` or not.  You also shouldn't duplicate your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to represent a player on a grid in four in a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345357/how-to-represent-a-player-on-a-grid-in-four-in-a-line)

Comment: It's a code with a little more progress on the question. and I don't understand well in words, can you explain it in code?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be the answer you're looking for, but hopefully will point you in the right direction.

```
// At this point Y = the selected column
// and X = 6 (presumably the end/bottom)
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            if (string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] == '●' || string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] == '○') {
                x -= 1;   // Right here X is now 5
                string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] = '●';  // and now you're setting string[4][]
                count++;
            } else {
                string[x - 1][(y - 1) * 2] = '●';  // and now you're setting string [5][]
                count++;
            }
        }
```

You see how you're never going to be able to set `string[0..3] which are the top 4 lines?  What would happen if you did something like this:

```
// Only determine the piece in one spot.
// Because after this point it doesn't matter what colour it is
// you're just going to find the next open spot from the bottom up
char piece = (count %2 == 0) ? 'r' : 'w';

// Now check all your lines from the bottom
for (int x = 6; x < 0; x--) {
   // does !string [x-1][y calc] contain 'r' or 'w'
   // string [x-1][y calc] = piece;
   // break;
}

// print/wins/etc.
```

Starting at the bottom, you work your way up until the spot doesn't contain `r` or `w` and then place it there.